# zend framework count the number of rows in mysql query

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to zend framework

I want to calculate number of rows in my query

this is my code:

```
$nm = new Zend_Db_Table('emp');
$row = $nm->fetchRow($nm->select()->where('id= ?', $a));
```

Comment: fetchRow will only fetch single row

Comment: a count(*) query can do that .or $nm->rowcount()

Answer (score 0):

yes you can try in this way to get total number of rows return by your sql query.

```
$select = $this->select();

$select->where('id= ?', $a);

$result=$this->fetchAll($select);

if(empty($result)){
    return false;
}else{
        echo "Total number of users : -> ".count($result->toArray());
}
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: This is good solution if you want to retrieve rows from a database and you want to use them in the letter code, and you want to count how many rows are returned by a database. Note that this is really bad construction if you just want to print the number of rows available in the database. On large tables, this construction may produce out of memory fatal error. Instead use select count(*) from tableName where id=idNumber.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing for the existance of a record by primary key then you can use `$nm->find($a)` and check for any results.

if you expect the result set to be small then you can do

```
$nm->fetchAll($nm->select()->where("id = ?", $a);
```

If you expect the result set to get big and all you are really after is the count then authoring a query that asks for the count of a field would probably make the most sense to keep the query from eating up a lot of server memory:

```
$row = $nm->getAdapter()->fetchRow("select count(*) as num_rows".
       " from ".$nm->info(Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract::NAME).
       " where ".$nm->getAdapter()->quoteInto("id = ?", $a));
echo "Users ".$row["num_rows"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Zend Framework 1, you can use `count()` function at the last of query for getting total number of rows in the table.

For example:

`$row  =  $nm->fetchAll($nm->select()->where('id = ?', $a ))->count();`

NOTE: This will only return total number of rows in the table. Output is Integer.